# Getting build failed while trying to generate apk for react native app

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I have made changes in the gradle.properties and build.gradle file of my project as mentioned in the doc:
gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=test.keystore 
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=test
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=test
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=test
```

build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
        release { 
            if (project.hasProperty('test.keystore')) {
                storeFile file(test.keystore) 
                storePassword "test"
                keyAlias "test"
                keyPassword "test"
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Getting the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.

  > No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.storePassword'.
  >   No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.keyAlias'.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by removing the values from siginingConfig{} as these values will be picked from the gradle

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because of assigning `keyAlias` to null. In my case it was an environment variable which was not defined